# How to get a set of elements and their classification based on a list

Tags: python, unix, output

I am not sure how to ask this question, and if I need Unix command or python code…

I have an input file with different elements with different names (genes)

## Input file:

```
gene1
gene2
gene3
gene4
gene5
..
```

And I got a list of same elements classified in different Groups as follow:

## focus file

```
Group1    gene1  gene2  gene3  gene4
Group2    gene4 gene5 gene6 gene7 gene8 gene9
Group3    gene10 gene11 gene12
…
```

I would like to obtain in my original input, the groups whose elements belong to, as follow:

## Output file

```
gene1 Group1
gene2 Group1
gene3 Group1
gene4 Group1 Group2
gene5 Group2
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the file's group like below:

```
import grp
import pwd
import os

def find_group(filename):
  stat_info = os.stat(filename)
  gid = stat_info.st_gid
  return grp.getgrgid(gid)[0]
```

Comment: Can you explain more please? I am very new to Python...Do I need to define my filename, in this case will be my focus list only right?  And how about my output, can I define in this code?

Comment: do you want to read the focus file and then generate and output file based on your example? or you are actually dealing with real files?

Comment: Yes, exactly! I have these 3 files, as my examples - but big files with different names for my groups and genes. I tried to include a didactic example.

Comment: the gens are real files or they are just some names?

Comment: genes are the elements in my input file and focal list. Only names.

Comment: then have a look here to see how File I/O work in python: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm